# Multiple inserts in Couchbase failing

Tags: couchbase, nosql

Couchbase newbie question:

I am trying to insert 1 million records in couchbase, but I see that nearly about 0.5 million records get inserted (Admin console shows 517365 as Item Count). 
Also, from the admin GUI, I can only see 1000 records (10 pages of 100 records each)

Am wondering where rest of the records are vanishing !

1)Can somebody help me with this ?

2)Which log file I should be looking at to find insertion failure errors ?

I suspect Couchbase has a internal queue. Once it gets full, further requests are dropped. If yes, then how to configure the queue size ?

PS: I tried looking into the logs C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\var\lib\couchbase\logs, but  couldn't figure out anything.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<URI> nodes = new ArrayList<URI>();
        String cbUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools";
        String dbName = "deafult";
        CouchbaseClient client = null;
        try {
            nodes.add(URI.create(cbUrl));

            client = new CouchbaseClient(nodes, dbName, "");

            insertRecords(client);

            System.out.println("Test Over");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // client.shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static void insertRecords(CouchbaseClient client) throws Exception {
        int num = 1000000;

        for (int n = 1; n <= num; n++) {
            System.out.println("Adding: " + n);
            client.set(n + "", 0, n + "");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you log the status of the operations? like `client.set('foo', 'bar').getStatus()`

Comment: Note that doing the what @avsej mentions here will cause your application to work properly also because the getStatus() call will wait for the operation to complete in order to get the return code of that operation.

Comment: I tried client.set('foo', 'bar').getStatus(). But I am get the {OperationStatus success=false:  Temporary failure} as status for many records. How can I configure the Couchbase buffer size ? I guess that should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The set operation in the Couchbase Java SDK is asynchronous. This means once the call returns there is no guarantee that you've even sent the operation to Couchbase since it may not have even been written to the network buffer yet. In order to make sure the operation has completed you need to call the get() function on the object (which is a Future) returned by the set() API.

In other words replace this line:

```
client.set(n + "", 0, n + "");
```

with this one:

```
client.set(n + "", 0, n + "").get();
```

Comment: Won't this make the call synchronous ? I guess there is some Queue that Couchbase uses. It would be good to know how to configure it or check its default size.

Comment: Oh...Since its a Future, the calls will be asynchronous, but there will still be an unnecessary get call for every set call. Is there a way to avoid it ?

Comment: In the shutdown() API you should be able to set a "wait for queues" value to true. Otherwise you will need to call the get() function on each future in order to make sure that the operation has completed. One thing you can also do is put all of your Future objects into a list and then call get() on all of them periodically. In bulk loading code I write I queue 1000 Futures then call get() on all of them and repeat until all of the data is loaded.

Comment: Brings me back to the question, is there anyway I can avoid making the unnecessary 'get' calls ? Also, how can I configure the internal buffer size that Couchbase uses (it will let me know how many insert queries I can make in one go) ? Can you please help me with these two questions ?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @mikewied's answer, to check that all 1,000,000 set operations have completed *without* having to call `.get()` explicitly on each one (and hence converting the calls from async to sync), you need to add a *listener* to each set which tracks how many of your operations have completed.

There's a nice example of how to do this in the [blog post](http://blog.couchbase.com/whats-new-couchbase-java-sdk-12) announcing Couchbase Java SDK 1.2 :-

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(100);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  OperationFuture<Boolean> future = client.set("key-" + i, "value");
  future.addListener(new OperationCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(OperationFuture<?> future) throws Exception {
      latch.countDown();
    }
  });
}
latch.await();
```

You create a `CountDownLatch`, initialised to how many documents you are set()ing, then register a listener which is called on completion of each set (but note the sets are still asynchronous). At the end you then call `await()` on the latch to ensure that all set operations have completed before continuing.

This approach is described in more detail in the [*Understanding and Using Asynchronous Operations*](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-java-1.4/index.html#understanding-and-using-asynchronous-operations) section of the Couchbase Java SDK Developer guide, along with a more compact syntax if you're using Java 8.

Comment: Note that it's still important to check the operation was successful as part of the onComplete function, as the operation may have 'completed' with an error code. As an example, you may want to check: future.getStatus().isSuccess()